# ERROR : valLists is undefined in pagination of table rows using AngularJS, AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, angularjs

I'm using part of  this code http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/webtech/web/pagination-and-sorting-of-data-table-using-angularjs/ for pagination an AngularJS, but I want to use data from MySQL DB table called 'user' ...
but i face an error that the valLists is undefined so it returns null and shows nothing.... I think that the type of data comes from select.php causes that, and I dnt know how to solve it .. any help!

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <br />
        <br />
        <div ng-app="myApp">
            <div ng-controller="TableCtrl">

                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="id">User Id
                            </th>
                            <th class="name">Name
                            </th>
                            <th class="phone">Phone
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="item in ItemsByPage[currentPage]">
                            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.phone}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li><a href="#" ng-click="firstPage()">First</a>

                    </li>
                    <li ng-repeat="n in range(ItemsByPage.length)"> <a href="#" ng-click="setPage()" ng-bind="n+1">1</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" ng-click="lastPage()">Last</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
        myApp.service('ListService', function () {                
            this.paged = function (valLists, pageSize) {
                retVal = [];                  
                for (var i = 0; i < valLists.length; i++) {
                    if (i % pageSize === 0) {
                        retVal[Math.floor(i / pageSize)] = [valLists[i]];
                    } else {
                        retVal[Math.floor(i / pageSize)].push(valLists[i]);
                    }
                }
                return retVal;
            };
        });

        var TableCtrl = myApp.controller('TableCtrl', function ($scope, ListService) {
            $scope.pageSize = 2;
            $scope.allItems = getData();

            $scope.resetAll = function () {
                $scope.List = $scope.allItems;
                $scope.newId = '';
                $scope.newName = '';
                $scope.newPhone = '';
                $scope.currentPage = 0;
            };
           function getData1(){
                 return [{
                         id : 33,
                         name : 'hala',
                         phone: 12345
                 }]
             };
            var d = new Array();
            function getData() {
                   $.ajax ({
                     url: "select.php",
                     type: 'POST',
                     //dataType: "json",
                     data: '',
                     success: function( data ) {
                        d = data;

                        // alert('succ');
                     },
                     error: function(  ) {

                         alert('Error select');
                     }
                     });    
                   //  alert(d);
               return d;
             }
$scope.pagination = function () {
                $scope.ItemsByPage = ListService.paged($scope.List, $scope.pageSize);

            };

            $scope.setPage = function () {
                $scope.currentPage = this.n;
            };

            $scope.firstPage = function () {
                $scope.currentPage = 0;
            };

            $scope.lastPage = function () {
                $scope.currentPage = $scope.ItemsByPage.length - 1;
            };

            $scope.range = function (input) {
                var ret = [];                    
                for (var i = 0; i < input; i++) {
                    if (i != 0 && i != input - 1) {
                        ret.push(i);
                    }
                }
                return ret;
            };

            $scope.resetAll();            
            $scope.pagination();

        });
```

select.php code

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include 'connect.php';
$db = new database();
$db->setDb_name('training');
$db->connect();

$db->select('user',"*");
$data = $db->getResult();    
echo json_encode($data);  
?>
```

here is select function:

```
public function select($table, $rows, $where = null){        
    $case = 0;   

    if($this->tableExists($table))
    {          
       $q = ' SELECT ' .$rows.' FROM '.$table;
        $query = @mysql_query($q);                   

        $this->numresults = mysql_num_rows($query);
        for($i = 0; $i < $this->numresults; $i++)
        {
            $r = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            $key = array_keys($r); 
            for($x = 0; $x < count($key); $x++)
            {
                // Sanitizes keys so only alphavalues are allowed
                if(!is_int($key[$x]))
                {
                    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 1)
                        $this->result[$i][$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]];
                    else if(mysql_num_rows($query) < 1)
                        $this->result = null; 
                    else
                        $this->result[$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]]; 
                }
               // $this->result[$i][$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]];
            }
        }   
       // print_r ($this->result)."<br/>";


   }
    else
        return false; 

}
```

and getResult() function:

```
public function getResult() {
    return $this->result;
}
```

NOTE1: when using function getData1() instead of getData() it works well.
NOTE2: i am sure that select function working well and bringing data like:

```
[{"id":"3","name":"newname","phone":"321"},
{"id":"4","name":"nnnnnnnnnnn","phone":"66555566"},      {"id":"10","name":"dss","phone":"45321"},    {"id":"11","name":"www","phone":"1234"},    {"id":"15","name":"fghjkl","phone":"34567890"}]
```

Comment: This is because you don't know the meaning of `asynchronous` in `ajax`

Comment: can you explain please, or tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to us angular's $http service. Something like this.

```
var TableCtrl = myApp.controller('TableCtrl', function ($scope, ListService, $http) {
  // ...
  $http.post('select.php')
       .success(function(response) {
          $scope.allItems = response;
       });

   // ...   
}
```

Comment: the same error is still appearing ..
and i used `alert(response)`  and showed alerting include this `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`
do you know why?

Comment: use console log to see what's actually happening. Using alert() it's not that helpful. That response should contain the data from your php. And you can handle the logic (for pagination) before allocating the data to the $scope.alItems